# Show current branch and coloring on Linux (like Git Bash on Windows)

Tags: linux, git, git-bash

On Git Bash on Windows I get nice coloring and the current branch is shown, like this:

[image]

How can I get the same coloring and prompt on Linux? On Linux I use the regular terminal, which doesn't show the current branch.

Comment: There are dozens of packages with fancy prompt settings. Pick whichever one you like; make sure it's for the *shell* you like. Arpit mentions zsh below, which requires switching from bash to zsh.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to retain the same coloring of your existing linux terminal and also show the current git branch, you can add the following to your default PS1.

PS1 basically tells your bash prompt what to display.
Ref: [How to Change / Set up bash custom prompt (PS1) in Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the default PS1 is found under `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then` in the ~/.bashrc file.

Steps:

1. Open the ~/.bashrc file and find `if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then`
2. Define the following bash function (Thanks @Nogoseke) above the if statement (You can define it anywhere above the PS1 value in the file).

```bash
#show git branch
show_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
```

3. Update the PS1 values to the following:

```bash
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[31m\]\$(show_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ "
else
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w \$(show_git_branch)\$ "
fi
```

The entire thing should look something like this:

```bash
#show git branch
show_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[31m\]\$(show_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$ "
else
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w \$(show_git_branch)\$ "
fi
```

4. Save the changes and restart your terminal.

It should looks something like this:
[image: Terminal with git branch]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bash,

I use the following on my ~/.bashrc:

```
show_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
 }
 export PS1="\[\033[0;37m\]\u@\h\[\033[0;37m\] \w \[\033[31m\]\$(show_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]$\[\033[00m\] "
```

A sample of what it looks like:

[image]

You just need to add the code to your .bashrc file and run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: It looks like `(master)$[00    m` when I try it.

Comment: @sashoalm My bad, there was an extra space from when I copied it, it is fixed now.

Comment: The name of your function is show_git_branch, then you use something called parse_git_branch.

Comment: @cheb1k4 Fixed it